Why is it impossible to define $\land$ and $\lor$ logical connectives in terms of the $\to$ and $\lnot$ connectives in intuitionistic logic?
In classical logic, accepting double negation elimination $\lnot\lnot p \rightarrow p$ allows us to simply define the $\land$ and $\lor$ connectives as follows:
$$p \land q := \lnot(p \to \lnot q)$$
$$p \lor q := \lnot p \to q$$
However, these definitions are clearly invalid in intuitionistic logic as it would be impossible to prove $q \lor p$ from $p \lor q$ and prove $p$ from $p \land q$.
I was wondering why there does not exist a suitable equivalent definition that is also valid in intuitionistic logic.

If there were, how could there still be a difference between classical and intuitionistic?

@HagenvonEitzen Are you saying that if it were possible to define $\land$ and $\lor$ in terms of $\to$ and $\lnot$, then from a metatheoretical perspective, that would mean that classical and intuitionistic logic would be equivalent (which is obviously not the case)?

In general when axiomatising these logics one tends to accept a connective $\top$ or $\bot$ in the language; in the presence of $\neg$, having one is equivalent to having the other. When you have $\bot$, then in turn it suffices to have $\rightarrow$, because $\neg a= a\rightarrow \bot$. So we may reformulate your question as: why is the $\{\rightarrow,\bot\}$-reduct of intuitionistic logic not equivalent to full intuitionistic logic?
The easiest proofs of this kind of result I know go by a sort of soundness argument: show that you can find a semantics $S$ for a logic $L$ such that $L$ is sound with respect to $S$, but $S$ does not interpret the additional connectives. In this case, the easiest proof I know is using algebraic semantics. We can axiomatise the implication-bot reduct of intuitionistic logic (let us call it $\mathsf{IPC}_{\rightarrow}$, which results in so called (bounded) "Hilbert Algebras" (See for example here). If the conjunction was definable in some way, there would be a term $t(x_{1},x_{2})$ in the language with $\{\rightarrow,\bot\}$ such that $t(x_{1},x_{2})$ satisfies the conditions of the conjunction. This means that $t(x_{1},x_{2})$ would be a definable expansion of Hilbert algebras forming a semilattice order. In the finite case, semilattices are indeed lattices. But there exist Hilbert algebras which are not lattices: every (bounded) poset can be given a Hilbert algebra structure, so picking a poset which is not a lattice provides such an example.
Let me know if you are not familiar with algebraic arguments; I suspect that there might be more elementary proofs in Chagrov and Zacharyaschev's "Modal Logic", but I have not had time to check now.
